# Android Studio Error: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25'

Tags: android

I am new to Android Studio and whenever I try to build my project, there is an error when Gradle syncs. It says:

"Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in C:Users\Samyuktha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Possible cause: Build properties not found for Android SDK Platform 25"

This happened when I first tried to build the app (I didn't modify anything). After this, I tried looking up solutions, and I went to the "Project Structure" menu and tried to change my compile SDK version and my build tools version. The problem is, the highest my compile SDK version goes is API 24 and the only available build tools option is 25.0.2. I set the compile SDK version to 24 and the build tools option to 25.0.2 and when I tried to run it, I got the error

"Error: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'. > java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing"

After this, I attempted to modify build.gradle, which is as follows (I changed compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, and com.android.support:appcompat-v7:):

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.text'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Other things I've tried**:

- I tried using the SDK manager in Android Studio and installing everything with API 25. I clicked "Show Package Details" and installed the ones that appeared after clicking that also were API 25.
- I tried running the standalone SDK manager in administrator mode and downloading build tools and everything under API 25 again

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Launch SDK Manager -> Install the packages (SDK platform 25 and SDK build Tools 25.0.2).

If after installing, still the error occurs -

Build -> Rebuild Project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one thing...go to local sdk location and see what are the build tools you have downloaded. try those build versions.

I also faced same problem. I tried below things.

1. removed all dependencies apart from 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
2. changed constraint layout to relativelayout/linearlayout
3. go to sdk location and check which build tools i have.. in my case i had 23.0.1
4. so i edited compileSdkVersion  as 23, buildToolsVersion as 23.0.1 support:appcompat as 23.1.1

Comment: I have build tools 25.0.0, 25.0.1, and 25.0.2. I tried all of them but I am still getting the same error "Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25'"

Comment: Not sure if this works.but can you try to go to Project Structure and select app module and change build version to 25.0.0/25.0.1/25.0.2.